# Как достать информацию из div c помощью Jsoup на Java?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Хочу получить из кода [страницы](https://yandex.ru/covid19/stat) информацию, используя библиотеку **Jsoup**, но никакие методы не помогают. До этого в примере брал информацию из тегов типа `table` и `tr`, все получалось.

[image: Код страницы]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://yandex.ru/covid19/stat";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
    String string = doc.getElementsByClass("today-category__value").first().ownText();// Один из способов
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Данные на странице отображаются после отображения HTML. Изучайте какой запрос идёт на получение данных и его используйте. JSOUP вам тут не поможет.  И молитесь, чтобы не пришлось браузер эмулировать.